# How fast does the accept() in ServerSocket accepts client request?

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a program that accepts requests from a client. Client sends request sequentially. I've observed that if client sends 3 requests. It will process all the request but it has a delay of 5 seconds before it will process the next request. For this sample it will take more than 15 seconds before it can process the 3 requests.

Is there a configuration in the network, OS or anywhere that could remove the said delay?

EDIT: Just to add. Each request that is finished, I close the corresponding socket.

Comment: use socket multi threading

Comment: There's no way the socket layer itself is causing this.  Could be the network (i.e., there's some huge latency between the client and the server).  It could also be something you're doing on your end, some mistake of programming.  The `accept()` should basically take no more time than receiving the packet itself.

Comment: Is your Request-Handling done in the same Thread as you're calling `accept()`? Did you measure how much time your handling needs?

Comment: @codeflush.dev The request-handling is passed on to a different thread. Per my observation, it only take 0.5-0.6 seconds per request.